# How to follow (tail -f) the latest file (matching a pattern) in a directory and call as alias with parameter

Tags: linux, bash, tail

I have a directory full of log files and I would like a bash oneline command to follow the latest log file that matches a pattern (e.g. "logfile*"). Basically I have a line that should work, just it does not...

`tail -f $(ls -1rt logfile* | tail -n 1)`

When I test only part of the command like so

```
ls -1rt logfile* | tail -n 1
logfile_20210111_105242.log
```

It will give me the latest log filename that I want to follow:

but adding the `tail -f` I get following response:

```
tail -f $(ls -1rt logfile* | tail -n 1)
tail: cannot open ''$'\033''[0m'$'\033''[00mlogfile_20210111_105242.log'$'\033''[0m' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

EDIT: Also, any idea how best to use this in an alias with parameters? most reasearch indicates a function in `.bashrc` has to be used, but I also found someone saying it should be possible by using `!:1` as variables.

EDIT2: Solution

Step1: use the solution from comments below

```
tail -f $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'logfile*' -printf '%Ts/%f\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -d/ -f2)
```

Step2: put it in `.alias` and make it work with a paramter for a filepattern

```
alias tailf="tail -f $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '\!:1' -printf '%Ts/%f\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -d/ -f2)"
```

EDIT3: While the alias seems to work, unfortunately it will tail all files matching the pattern passed as parameter. When I hardcode the pattern in the alias definition it works perfectly just tailing the latest file matching the pattern.

Thanks

Comment: You've got color codes in your filename. Let me guess, you have `ls` aliased to set `--color=always`? Turn that off; the `--color=auto` default is there for good reasons.

Comment: That said, it's deeply inappropriate to use `ls` for this purpose at all; see [Why you should never parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: ...[BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) describes how to _safely_ find the newest file in a directory, in a way that (unlike `ls`) will work for all possible filenames. "All possible filenames" is a wide scope -- filenames can contain spaces, newlines, quotes, unicode characters; it's unwise to write code that makes assumptions.

Comment: Indeed there is color coding, but it's a company server so this change might not be welcomed. Thanks for the the links, very good general info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tail -f "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "logfile*" -printf "%Ts/%f\n" | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -d/ -f2)"
```

Tail the result of the find command. Search for files prefixed with logfile in the current directory and print the epoch time of creation as well as the file path and name, separated by a forward slash Pipe this through to sort and then print the latest entry with tail -1 before stripping out to to leave only the file path with cut.

Comment: What if my filename contains a comma, though? ;)

Comment: Actually, in this case, the path is not required as we are already in the directory and so I have amended with "/" as the separator

Comment: Why not write the answer to use NULs, which _can't possibly_ exist in filenames, instead of newlines (which can)? You're already assuming GNU `find`; as long as you also assume GNU `sort` and `tail`, support for NUL delimiters is built-in.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. I even found how to make this work as alias with parameters:

`alias tailf="tail -f $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '\!:1' -printf '%Ts/%f\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -d/ -f2)"`

so I can just call it like `tailf logfile_202001*`for instance.

Comment: I'm happy to help. If you would kindly accept the solution as an answer, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will do that... just found out though, that there seems to be an issue with the parameter/variable:

While the alias seems to work, unfortunately it will tail all files matching the pattern passed as parameter. When I hardcode the pattern in the alias definition it works perfectly just tailing the latest file matching the pattern.

Comment: @Phil, in general, if you want to take parameters, you should be using a function instead of an alias. Aliases can't really take parameters at all -- they're just prefix substitution, whereas a function can be written to handle parameters however you want it to.

Comment: @Phil, ...so, for example, you could start your function with `local -a findArgs=( ); (( $# )) || set -- 'logfile*'; for arg do findArgs+=( -name "$arg" -o ); done`, and then use `find . -maxdepth 1 '(' "${findArgs[@]}" -false ')'` to substitute each argument into the `find` command.

Comment: @Phil, ...anyhow, if you need more guidance than that, I'd suggest asking a new question, since this one has already been adequately answered.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, I asked the remaining question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65825241/alias-with-parameter-behaves-differently-than-its-underlying-command)